# array returns error undefined index in php

Tags: php, arrays

The index 4 exisits in array rating but i get error...if i undo the comments $write=4 then it works fine.

```
foreach($writers[$i] as $write)
      {
      echo "writer: $write  -  rating: ";
      print_r($rating);
//$write=4;
      echo "<br>". $rating[$write] ;

}
```

the above code gives

```
    writer: 4 
Notice: Undefined index: 4 in D:\wamp\www\shazia\CRM\EffortTrackUpload\admin\cron.php on line 232
```

The array rating gives:

```
Array ( [3] => 5.1 [4] => 6 [5] => 5.2 [6] => 5 [8] => 5 [9] => 5 [10] => 5 [11] => 4 [12] => 3.6 [13] => 5 [14] => 5.1 )
```

can anyone please help me explain what i am doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: `var_dump($rating);` --- If php says there is no item 4 - then there is not. Check once again.

Comment: Here is what the var_dump returned:it does have index 4: array(11) { [3]=> string(3) "5.1" [4]=> string(1) "6" [5]=> string(3) "5.2" [6]=> string(1) "5" [8]=> string(1) "5" [9]=> string(1) "5" [10]=> string(1) "5" [11]=> string(1) "4" [12]=> string(3) "3.6" [13]=> string(1) "5" [14]=> string(3) "5.1" }

Comment: Just checking if you uncomment your assignment to $write and make it like this: $write="4"; 
Does it still print 6?

Comment: better yet do a var_dump on $write

Comment: @anubhav no i just took var_dump($rating); @Stephen var_dump($wriet) returned: string(2) " 4"

Comment: @Shazia , please edit your question with the result of `var_dump($writers)` not `var_dump($write)`

Comment: $write should equal "4" not " 4"

Comment: @diEcho var-dump($writers) returns:array(3) { [1]=> array(1) { [2]=> string(2) " 4" } [2]=> array(3) { [1]=> string(0) "" [2]=> string(0) "" [3]=> string(0) "" } [3]=> array(3) { [1]=> string(0) "" [2]=> string(0) "" [3]=> string(0) "" } }

Comment: Ok that's what I thought $write is of type string but your $rating array has key on integer 4 that's why when you uncomment it works.

Comment: @grc when i added  $write=trim($write); its working..Thanks everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your comment, the issue is that $write is a string - " 4", but the array index is just an integer 4.

Work out why the 4 is padded with space in the $writers[$i] array, if you are getting the array from elsewhere you could use intval($write) to get the correct value.

Answer (score 1):

Either `$writers[$i]` is undefined when `$i = 4`, or `$rating[$write]` is undefined when `$write = 4`. It will be whichever one is on line 232 corresponding to your error message.

Use `if(isset($writers[$i]))` to prevent the error.

**Edit** From your comment, I'd say it is `$rating[4]` that is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($writers[$i] as $write)
      {
      echo "writer: $write  -  rating: ";
      print_r($rating);
//$write=4;
      echo "<br>". $rating[trim($write)] ; // use trim so that it will replace " 4" to "4"

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach($writers as $write){
   //code here
}
```

Is how it should be written :)

Comment: $writers is a multidimentional array

Comment: OPs `foreach`, I'm assuming is nested within another loop.

Comment: @Russel Dias yes it is a nested

Comment: Forgive me, i assumed that it was not nested.